# Pandas group by dense rank partitioned by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that contains `id, building_id, built_year, registered_year` and some other columns.

In the df, an id can contain multiple `building_id`. However, the data is not clean. There can be multiple `building_id` but different `built_year` and `registered_year`. I assume that the building got renovated, but rather than updating the data, it's been added.

So the plan for me is to ***rank*** the buildings based on the order of `built_year`, `registered_year`.

`built_year` is in the format 1999 and `registered_year` is in the format 1999-10-10 10:10:10+00:00

| id | building_id | built_year | registered_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 | 1999 | 1999-10-10 10:10:10+00:00 |
| 1 | 89 | 1925 | 1925-10-10 10:10:10+00:00 |
| 1 | 90 | 2001 | 2000-10-10 10:10:10+00:00 |
| 1 | 90 | 2009 | 2000-10-10 10:10:10+00:00 |

This is what I have:

```py
df['built_year'] = pd.to_numeric(df['built_year'], errors='coerce')
df['registered_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['registered_year'], errors='coerce')

df['rank'] = df.groupby('building_id')[['built_year', 'registered_year']] \
               .transform(lambda x: x.rank(method = 'dense', ascending = False))
```

---

| id | building_id | built_year | registered_year | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 | 1999 | 1999-10-10 10:10:10+00:00 | 3 |
| 1 | 89 | 1925 | 1925-10-10 10:10:10+00:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 90 | 2001 | 2000-10-10 10:10:10+00:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 90 | 2009 | 2000-10-10 10:10:10+00:00 | 1 |

Well, the code would work if I had only ranked it over one column, for instance, on only `built_year`. But by adding more columns, it gives me the following:

> *ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column rank*

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Would you mind providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it's possible to investigate what's going on?

Comment: I've never used `df.rank`, but it sounds like you just need to match the number of columns, like `df[['rank_built', 'rank_registered']] = ...`. If you provided a [mre], I could at least check if that works. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Sorting, followed by grouping and cumulatively counting (in descending order) should return the same desired result: `df["rank"] = df.sort_values(by=["built_year", "registered_year"]).groupby().cumcount(ascending=False) + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) in this case:

```
df['rank'] = (df.sort_values(['built_year', 'registered_year'], ascending=False)
                .groupby('building_id').cumcount().add(1))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   id  building_id  built_year           registered_year  rank
0   1           90        1999 1999-10-10 10:10:10+00:00     3
1   1           89        1925 1925-10-10 10:10:10+00:00     1
2   1           90        2001 2000-10-10 10:10:10+00:00     2
3   1           90        2009 2000-10-10 10:10:10+00:00     1
```

If you use [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html), all columns will be ranked individually:

```
>>> (df.groupby('building_id')[['built_year', 'registered_year']]
       .transform('rank', method='dense', ascending=False))

   built_year  registered_year
0         3.0              2.0
1         1.0              1.0
2         2.0              1.0
3         1.0              1.0
```